# Как маcсив записать в файл/ прочитать из файла?

Tags: php, массивы

Здравствуйте! Помогите: не могу добить код. 
Есть массив `array('vkShare','Google','VKontakte','FacebookExternalHit')`, и я его содержимое записываю в файл построчно 
YandexBot
Googlebot 
Googlebot-Image
Mediapartners-Google

и вот из файла не могу вывести, а через array работает

```
    $list = file("data/bot.dat"); //так не хочет работать 

$list = array('vkShare','Google','VKontakte','FacebookExternalHit');//а так работает
       foreach($list as $row => $botname) {

       //var_dump($row);
            if (stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], $botname) !== false) {
                return $list[$row]; // получаем имя бота из массива

            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

$name = is_bot();

if ($name) {
$botname = $name ;
} else {
$botname = "Посетитель";
}
```

Comment: 02: var_dump($list):

Comment: так выводит лист а на сайте выводит посетитель , я вызываю бота через яндекс шаре

Comment: вот приходил  Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; U; MailRuConnect/1.0)  а показало посетитель

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.var-export.php

Answer (score 0):

Заработало так:

```
$list = explode(PHP_EOL, file_get_contents("data/bot.dat"));
$list = array_map('trim',$list);
```

Comment: Теперь-то понял в чем дело? Идеальный вариант - правильно форматировать конец строки в исходном файле.